# PHPUnit returns code -1

Tags: php, phpunit

Why PHPUnit return -1, when all test run OK.

```
phpunit application/models2/Sima/UserTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.29 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/tests/phpunit.xml

.

Time: 866 ms, Memory: 19.25Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

Comment: Where are you seeing a return of -1?

Comment: I saw it in Bamboo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519744/bamboo-phpunit-fail

Comment: The command you used in that question was `/usr/bin/phpunit --log-junit /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/test-reports/phpunit.xml --coverage-html /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/test-reports/coverage/html --stderr`, which is very different from the `phpunit application/models2/Sima/UserTest.php` above. Are you sure all of the directories in the longer command exist and that you have correct permissions?

Comment: Commands are different but the results are the same. Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Does `phpunit application/models2/Sima/UserTest.php` also return a `-1`?

Comment: You need a simple shell script: `#!/bin/bash` (new line) `phpunit application/models2/Sima/UserTest.php` (new line) `echo "last command returned: $?"`

Comment: Oops. 0. But in bamboo ...

Comment: Try it using the other (long) phpunit command in the shell script; this sounds like a permissions error to me.

Comment: Other (long)? What do you mean?

Comment: `/usr/bin/phpunit --log-junit /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/test-reports/phpunit.‌​xml --coverage-html /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/test-reports/coverage‌​/html --stderr`

Comment: So your shell script would be `#!/bin/bash` (new line) `/usr/bin/phpunit --log-junit /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/test-reports/phpunit.‌​‌​xml --coverage-html /home/bamboo/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/SIMA-MAIN-JOB1/test-reports/coverage‌​‌​/html --stderr` (new line) `echo "last command returned: $?"`

Comment: last command returned: 0

Comment: Then it's either a bamboo problem or a typo when you put it in bamboo; it's impossible to tell from this info. But phpunit is returning 0, as it should.

Comment: Thanks ... But what to do with bamboo...

Comment: Omg ... It's was wrong working directory of Bamboo! Thanks a lot, Ed!